# Check if variable is set and then echo it without repeating?

Tags: php, variables, isset

Is there a concise way to check if a variable is set, and then echo it without repeating the same variable name?

Instead of this:

```
<?php
    if(!empty($this->variable)) {
        echo '<a href="', $this->variable, '">Link</a>';
    }
?>
```

I'm thinking about something in the lines of this C-style pseudocode:

```
<?php
    echo if(!empty($this->variable, '<a href="', %s, '">Link</a>'));
?>
```

PHP has [sprintf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php), but it doesn't quite do what I was hoping for. If course I could make a method/function out of it, but surely there must be a way to do it "natively"?

Update:
Ternary operations would also repeat the `$this->variable` part, if I understood it?

```
echo (!empty($this->variable) ? '<a href="',$this->variable,'">Link</a> : "nothing");
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any shorthand for that. If you use it a lot, I would anyway recommend creating a function for that.

Comment: Ternary operation (`(bool) ? value : default `) is not an option?

Answer (score 19):

The closest you can get to what you are looking for is using short form of ternary operator (available since PHP5.3)

```
echo $a ?: "not set"; // will print $a if $a evaluates to `true` or "not set" if not
```

But this will trigger "Undefined variable" notice. Which you can obviously suppress with `@`

```
echo @$a ?: "not set";
```

Still, not the most elegant/clean solution.

So, the cleanest code you can hope for is

```
echo isset($a) ? $a: '';
```

Comment: Often I'll use a technique similar to this but with empty which also accounts for empty strings

Comment: Good thinking. Shame there isn't an inbuilt PHP function and surprising too.

Answer (score 17):

**Update:**

PHP 7 introduces a new feature: [**Null coalescing operator**](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)

Here is the example from php.net.

```
<?php
// Fetches the value of $_GET['user'] and returns 'nobody'
// if it does not exist.
$username = $_GET['user'] ?? 'nobody';
// This is equivalent to:
$username = isset($_GET['user']) ? $_GET['user'] : 'nobody';

// Coalescing can be chained: this will return the first
// defined value out of $_GET['user'], $_POST['user'], and
// 'nobody'.
$username = $_GET['user'] ?? $_POST['user'] ?? 'nobody';
?>
```

For those not using PHP7 yet here is my original answer...

I use a small function to achieve this:

```
function ifset(&$var, $else = '') {
  return isset($var) && $var ? $var : $else;
}
```

Example:

```
$a = 'potato';

echo ifset($a);           // outputs 'potato'
echo ifset($a, 'carrot'); // outputs 'potato'
echo ifset($b);           // outputs nothing
echo ifset($b, 'carrot'); // outputs 'carrot'
```

---

**Caveat**: As Inigo pointed out in a comment below one undesirable side effect of using this function is that it can modify the object / array that you are inspecting. For example:

```
$fruits = new stdClass;
$fruits->lemon = 'sour';
echo ifset($fruits->peach);
var_dump($fruits);
```

Will output:

```
(object) array(
  'lemon' => 'sour',
  'peach' => NULL,
)
```

Comment: I thought of this as well. However, the following problem arises:
$data = [];
$data['a'] = 2;
echo ifset($data['b']);
var_dump($data);
 Will return array(2) { ["a"]=> int(2) ["b"]=> NULL }. So the ifset function actually modifies the original data object...

Comment: You are totally right Inigo - I'd never realised that as don't usually use this with arrays. Looks like we'll have to wait till we are using PHP7 for a solution that definitely doesn't modify the original object.

Answer (score -1):

Use [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)  function of php like this:

```
<?php

  echo $result = isset($this->variable) ? $this->variable : "variable not set";

 ?>
```

i think this will help.

Comment: The `$this->variable` would still repeat in the "do something" part. I'd like to do it without repeating it multiple times in the command. (downvote wasn't mine...)