# If variable not empty display variable without repeating variable name

Tags: php, if-statement, syntax

Hello there do you know a way for writing this in PHP without repeating the variable name?

```
if($abcdefg["blaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla"]!=="") {
    echo $abcdefg["blaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla"];
} else if($abcdefg["evenMoreBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla"]!=="") {
    echo $abcdefg["evenMoreBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla"];
} else if($abcdefg["stillAlotBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla"]!=="") {
    echo $abcdefg["stillAlotBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla"];
}
```

Of course you can write

```
$a = $abcdefg["blaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla"];
$b = $abcdefg["evenMoreBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla"];
$c = $abcdefg["stillAlotBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla"];

if($a) { echo $a; } else if($b) { echo $b; } else if ($c) { echo $c; }
```

This is a bit shorter but I still wonder if there is some syntactical nice thing to write it without variable repetition.

Ternary operator does not solve the problem because of the "elseif" I think.

Comment: either spell it out in full, or copy/reference to another variable and use that. there are no "shortcuts". that or just don't use insanely long variable/key names...

Comment: It chitter chatters, just like birds and chickens.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if variable is set and then echo it without repeating?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970220/check-if-variable-is-set-and-then-echo-it-without-repeating)

Comment: yeah, was just going to suggest a ternary ^

Comment: The problem with ternary is the "elseif" i guess? However i like the answers of bitworking and rizier123 both solutions are nice.

Comment: Hmm I like the concept of the complex ternary but after a short check I cant see how it solves the core of the problem yet?

Comment: It was a thought. It looked to be promising at the time ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a variable declaration in the if condition:

```
if(($var = $abcdefg["blaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla"]) !== "") {
    echo $var;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work for you:

Just loop through all indexes, which you want to check and print them if they pass the if statement, e.g.

```
$indexes = ["blaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla", "evenMoreBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla", "stillAlotBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla"];

foreach($indexes as $key) {
    if($abcdefg[$key] !== "") {
        echo $abcdefg[$key];
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about declaring a function for the ... hmmm ... functionnality?

```
function echoNotEmpty($s)
{
    if ($s !== '') echo $s;
}
echoNotEmpty($abcdefg["blaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla"]);
echoNotEmpty($abcdefg["evenMoreBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla"]);
echoNotEmpty($abcdefg["stillAlotBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla"]);
```

Or even shorter:

```
echo $abcdefg["blaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla"];
echo $abcdefg["evenMoreBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla"];
echo $abcdefg["stillAlotBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBlaBla"];
```

I mean, if you don't want to echo empty string and you still echo them, who cares?

Comment: The problem is the "elseif" (there are maybe two strings which are not empty, and only the first should be echoed).